# Java: removeIf sum of grouping of 2 fields equals 0

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I have a list of items. Each item has 3 properties: name, section and amount. The amount can be positive/negative. The same item can be several times in the same section.

I want to group the items in the list by section and name. If the sum of this grouping equals 0 - remove all the items with this section and name.

I got this far

```
items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemData::getSection))....
```

Now I need the second grouping and compare it to 0 in order to add it as a predicate to removeIf

```
items.removeIf(item -> predicate(item));
```

Comment: But how can the grouping be 0 ? Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group the `ItemData` based on `section` and `name` with sum of `amount` as value

```
   Map<String,Long> result = details.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(det -> det.getSection()+"_"+det.getName(),
                    Collectors.summingLong(det->det.getAmount())));
```

And then remove the entries from `Map` having value `!=0`

```
   result.entrySet().removeIf(det->det.getValue() != 0);
```

And then remove the elements from `items` list having entry in `Map` with key comparison

```
items.removeIf(item -> result.containsKey(item.getSection()+"_"+item.getName()));
```

You can also eliminate the entries having value `0` by using stream

```
Map<String,Long> result = details.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(det -> det.getSection()+"_"+det.getName(),
                    Collectors.summingLong(det->det.getCount())))
           .entrySet()
           .stream()
           .filter(entry->entry.getValue()==0)
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: Your reply not only answered my question but also cleared my thoughts regarding other solutions I read but failed to fully understand so thanks for that too. Oh, and I LOVE Deadpool!

Comment: or in one step without `entrySet.removeIf...`, simply use grouped `Map` as `items.removeIf(item -> result.get(item.getSection()+"_"+item.getName())==0);`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a `BiPredicate` which accepts an `Item` and `List<Item>`

```
BiPredicate<Item,List<Item>> biPred = 
    (item, list) -> list.stream()
                        .filter(i -> i.getName().equals(item.getName()) && 
                                     i.getSection().equals(item.getSection()))
                        .mapToLong(Item::getAmount)
                        .sum() == 0;

myList.removeIf(e -> biPred.test(e, myList));
```